# Triangle inequality problem

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $d(x,y)= 11$ and $d(x,z) = 7$, then what is the minimum possible value of $d(y,z)$? I think it is zero. $d(x,z) \le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. However I have a problem because $d(y,z)=d(z,y)$ so this would seem to imply the minimum for $d(y,z)$ would be $4$ instead of zero, because $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y)$.

Comment: Two of the sides of a "triangle" are $7$ and $11$. The sum of the two smallest sides is $\ge$ the largest side.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=d(y,z)$.

Then $t+7\geq 11$ **and** $11+7\geq t$ **and** $11+t\geq 7$.

So $4\leq t \leq 18$. So the minimum possible value of $d(y,z)$ should be 4, not zero.